# How to suppress the DHCP DNS servers with specific IPs in UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, network-adapter

I want to suppress the default DNS servers that are assigned by the DHCP. I have two specific IPs (say: 8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4). I tried to add them from the GUI: `System Settings -> Network -> Wired -> Options -> IPv4 Settings (tab) -> Additional DNS Servers`. I added them as follows (comma separated) `8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`

Unfortunately, when I double click the connection icon (the two arrows) and check the connection `information`, I still find the DHCP DNS servers and one of the two IPs I added appear under `Ternary DNS`.

I then tried to navigate to:

```
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Then add the line:
`supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4` 
Nothing changed.

I tried to restart my network interface. I want the interface name. I executed `ifconfig -a`, I got 3 interfaces: `enp0s31f6`, `lo`, `wlp2s0`. The one that has the IP is the `enp0s31f6` which I believe is the wired one that I am concerned about. When I try to restart using: `sudo ifdown enp0s31f6 && sudo ifup enp0s31f6`, I get error that the interface does not exist.

Can you plese help me how to suppress my DHCP DNSs with two other public DNS.

Comment: In 16.04 the DNS is handled by DNSmasq and the namles servers are set by interface. You can set specific name servers by editing the connection in the NetworkManager GUI.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide more specific answer please (steps). Is what you refer to  `network manager` is the same GUI that appear to me when I double-click the wired connection (two arrows up and down)? If yes, this is what I did but the DHCP DNS seems to have priority based on this GUI (DHCP DNS appear as primary and secondary, and the one I added appears as ternary). If you know exact answer, please post exact steps.